# Fill pandas dataframe with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have 4 dataframes for 4 newspapers (newspaper1,newspaper2,newspaper3,newspaper4])
which have a single column for author name.

Now I'd like to merge these 4 dataframes into one, which has 5 columns: author, and newspaper1,newspaper2,newspaper3,newspaper4 which contain 1/0 value (1 for author writing for that newspaper)

```
import pandas as pd 

listOfMedia =[newspaper1,newspaper2,newspaper3,newspaper4]
merged = pd.DataFrame(columns=['author','newspaper1','newspaper2', 'newspaper4', 'newspaper4'])
```

while this loop does what I intended (fills the merged df author columns with the name):

```
for item in listOfMedia:
    merged.author = item.author
```

I can't figure out how to fill the newspapers columns with the 1/0 values...

```
for item in listOfMedia:
    if item == newspaper1:
        merged['newspaper1'] = '1'
    elif item == newspaper2:
        merged['newspaper2'] = '1'
    elif item == newspaper3:
        merged['newspaper3'] = '1'
    else:
        merged['newspaper4'] = '1'
```

I keep getting error

*During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
TypeError: attrib() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert'*
Tried to google that error but didn't help me identify what the problem is.
What am I missing here? I also think there must be smarter way to fill the newspaper/author matrix, however don't seem to be able to figure out even this simple way. I am using jupyter notebook.

Comment: A simple way would be to add to the 4 DFs all the "newspaperX" columns, set the appropriate column to 1 for each DF and then combine (actually "append") all the DFs into one.

Comment: i think you need `.loc` `df.loc[:,listOfMedia] = 1` i think what would be better if you can show your starting and intended dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are setting all rows to 1 so use:

```
for col in merged.columns:
    merged[col].values[:] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a guess at what I think your dataframes look like.

```
newspaper1 = pd.DataFrame({'author': ['author1', 'author2', 'author3']})
newspaper2 = pd.DataFrame({'author': ['author1', 'author2', 'author4']})
newspaper3 = pd.DataFrame({'author': ['author1', 'author2', 'author5']})
newspaper4 = pd.DataFrame({'author': ['author1', 'author2', 'author6']})
```

Firstly we will copy the dataframes so we don't affect the originals:

```
newspaper1_temp = newspaper1.copy()
newspaper2_temp = newspaper2.copy()
newspaper3_temp = newspaper3.copy()
newspaper4_temp = newspaper4.copy()
```

Next we replace the index of each dataframe with the author name:

```
newspaper1_temp.index = newspaper1['author']
newspaper2_temp.index = newspaper2['author']
newspaper3_temp.index = newspaper3['author']
newspaper4_temp.index = newspaper4['author']
```

Then we concatenate these dataframes (matching them together by the index we set):

```
merged = pd.concat([newspaper1_temp, newspaper2_temp, newspaper3_temp, newspaper4_temp], axis =1)
merged.columns = ['newspaper1', 'newspaper2', 'newspaper3', 'newspaper4']
```

And finally we replace NaN's with 0 and then non-zero entries (they will still have the author names in them) as 1:

```
merged = merged.fillna(0)
merged[merged != 0] = 1
```